Why elasticsearch does not accept JSON fields as text?
I have a field that contains non-deterministic JSON objects. I want this field to be indexed as a simple text so I can search its content later if needed.
But I get error from elastic 'Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:351'. Seems like it detects it is JSON and rejects it.
Is there a way to make it work or my approach is not right?
[edit] llama3:8B said:
1. Use a dynamic mapping
Elasticsearch has a feature called "dynamic mapping" which allows you to specify a single field with a dynamic type that can adapt to different data types based on the actual values.
You can define your field like this:
"properties": {
  "my_field": {
    "type": "object",
    "dynamic": true,
    "properties": {}
  }
}

This will allow Elasticsearch to automatically detect and index the different data types (e.g., object or text) within the my_field field.
2. Use a field with multiple mappings
You can define multiple mappings for the same field name, using the mappings property. For example:
"properties": {
  "my_field": {
    "type": ["object", "text"],
    "mappings": {
      "object": {
        "properties": {}
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

But I couldn't confirm these in my search.

That ollama code is wrong. Don't mind it.

It's possible but you need to serialize your JSON as text.
Let's say your field is called "json", instead of sending it like this
{
   "json": {
      "foo": {
         "bar": 3
      }
   }
}

You need to send it like this:
{
   "json": "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 3}}"
}

Although I'm not sure that you'll manage to "search" that field in an efficient way later on. But try it out.

Are you already using Logstash? Are all of your documents going through s single indexing component or are they being sent to ES from different places in your code?

I checked and noticed this part is not going through Logstash and I was mistaken. It is being sent to elk directly by its nodejs module (bunyan-elasticsearch).

One of my constraints is that changes to the code should be minimal. It is a big project and changes are spread in many places. Maybe it is possible to do such transformations in logstash but I am not sure. (It was my first comment which I couldn't edit). Now we know there is no Logstash in the middle.

What I'm saying is that if you're sending data to ES from many different places, you'll need to modify all those places anyway to send the data to Logstash instead.

Well I am trying to enable: false the fields for now as a solution.

Doing that will not allow you to query that field later on

Yes I do that for the fields I don't need them in a query to find their record then will access their value from _source.

I was reacting to what you said at the beginning of your question: "I want this field to be indexed as a simple text so I can search its content later if needed". Searching a field or getting it from source are really two different use cases.

Yes I want to do the former but as I don't know how, have to do the latter to prevent rejecting the docs. I also don't know what to do with the fields that must be indexed and are in conflict. To ignore files I set their type to 'object' and set 'enabled' to false. I believe the root of the problem is that my app is sending whatever log it puts in a file also to elk without reorganization.

If you want to search on specific fields from your json is better to index those fields. however you can index your json by dumping it:
import json
{
   "text": json.dumps(field)
}

you also can use dynamic mapping while creating index.
